# Fixture file not found in Ember project

Tags: ember.js

Is there a basic tutorial or guide on using Ember fixtures? I have gone through the [tilde training](http://www.tilde.io/events/introduction-to-ember-online/) but it drops right in the middle of a project and I am trying to start from Ember new following the same conventions taught in the course.

I have set up the following routes and fixture:

```
// routes/application.js
  import Ember from 'ember';
  import speakers from 'models/speaker-fixtures';

  export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       return speakers;
  });

// fixture app/models/speaker-fixtures.js
export default [{
  id: "1",
  twitterHandle: "foogirl",
  name: "foo girl",
  avatar: ""
}, {
  id: "2",
  twitterHandle: "fooboy",
  name: "foo boy",
  avatar: ""
}];

// adapter/application.js 
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

// serializer/application.js
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({});
```

<.code>

**error received** : 
File: project-voice/routes/application.js
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/../tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-VUc8t50a.tmp/models/speaker-fixtures.js'

Is there something I am missing that will help ember find my fixture file? This is my first attempt in creating an app outside a tutorial and I am a bit lost. *I also tried setting up the fixture in the model how it explains in the [embercli doc](http://www.ember-cli.com/#mocks-and-fixtures) and could not get that work.

Any push in the right direction would help tremendously. Thanks

Comment: hey, just a stupid question... in the comment, you have `app/model/speaker-fixtures.js` whereas in the import, `'models/speaker-fixtures'` - maybe it's just a typo? model vs models

Comment: it was a typo, it is in `app/models/speaker-fixtures.js`

Comment: What if you try a relative path `import '../models/speaker-fixtures';`? Also, given that you paid for the training, maybe they are available for questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path indeed needs to be relative.

```
import '../models/speaker-fixtures';
```